# How to write a date interval?

Tags: datetime

What is a correct way of writing a date interval?

```
a) Jun 2010 -- Aug 2012
b) Jun 2010--Aug 2012
c) Jun 2010 - Aug 2012
d) Jun 2010-Aug 2012
c) other?
```

Comment: @Xavier: In my opinion, this question isn't really a duplicate, since it is really more general. Note that the other duplicate candidate also contains dash-less answers.

Comment: Yes, it is related to these questions. My concern is should I put a spaces around the en-dash: is it a or b?

Comment: @Kimi Why is this a (La)TeX question at all? (No offence; just asking.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg, it is a typographical issue, and this is the best place I know to get a competent opinion. Also I'm writing a document in LaTeX, so there might be a LaTeX specific solution.

Comment: @Kimi Good point! I hope you find an adequate solution.

Answer (score 2):

`-` is used for hyphenation of words, as in: `open-minded`

`--` is used for separating numbers, such as: `1998--1999`

`---` is used for saying something in the middle of a sentence, e.g.: `I didn't look back ---at least not with my eyes--- as I walked away.`

The three of them produce a different output, as each one is little larger than the other.

For dates it depends on what format you are using, and I'm not aware of any "restrictions" about what to use, but personally I believe you should go with whatever looks best for you.

Comment: You've got `-` and `--` mixed up. `--` is the en-dash, used to separate ranges, while `-` is the hyphen, used to hyphenate words. See [When should I use an em-dash, an en-dash, and a hyphen?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen)

Comment: As for dates, the only correct form is to use `--`, as it's a range.

Comment: @Xavier, you're right, I took a look here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting#Dashes_and_hyphens